# gitlab compare - get raw patch / diff file

Tags: gitlab

### My situation

In both github and gitlab, I can compare two branches or refs in the UI:

- github: `https://github.com/*/*/compare/1.x...2.x`
- gitlab: `https://*.*.*/*/*/-/compare/1.x...2.x`

In github, I can append `.diff` or `.patch` to this comparison, to get a raw diff or patch file.

In gitlab, this does not work.

In gitlab, I *can* append `.patch` or `.diff` to a single commit url like `***/-/commit/***.diff, or to a merge request url like` ***/-/merge_requests/16.patch`. But it does not work on compare urls.

### Why do I need this?

I like to use these patch urls in package managers like composer, so I don't have to manually create the patch file and save it somewhere.

And sometimes I don't want to apply a single commit or a complete PR/MR, but a very specific range of commits.

### Question

How can I get the raw diff or patch file for a comparison in gitlab?

### Version of gitlab

The instance of gitlab I tried this with is https://git.drupalcode.org/. In the help it says the version is 15.11.7-ee.

I think I had the same experience with other gitlab instances.